# Получение пути к файлу exe

Tags: c#

Никак не могу понять, как получить корректный путь к файлу, необходимо получить путь
C:\Users\inact1ve\Desktop\Forescating Timeseries\TestApp\TestApp\influx, с учетом того, что C:\Users\inact1ve\Desktop\Forescating Timeseries\TestApp\TestApp будет изменяться,
Не находит файл при

```cs
p1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("influxd.exe");
p1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"\influx";
```

при таком коде попадаю в C:\influx

Как прописать корректный путь с учетом изменений?
Были идеи взять текущую директорию и отходить назад пока не получу нужную директорию, но не понимаю как

Comment: Так же не находит

Comment: А как вы собираетесь определить измененную директорию? Хорошо, предположим это рабочий стол - для него есть некое сокращение, которое даст верны путь, но `\TestApp\TestApp` - как программа должна понять что это то, что ей необходимо? Даже человек не всегда поймет. Найдите некие "ключевые точки", по которым вы сможете найти этот путь. Может это в корне вашего запускаемого приложения, может этот процесс уже запущен и из него можно взять путь? Короче без этого вы вряд ли сделаете такой динамический путь, слишком уж общий у вас он.

Comment: я не понял, что именно надо получить, что будет меняться, и что известно в момент запуска. Добавь недостающую информацию в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3991933/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного ошибся в условии, речь была о том, что при перемещении папки проекта запускались файлы из каталога в самом проекте. В таком случае необходимо прыгнуть на 3 каталога вверх, у меня получилось сделать.

```cs
p1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"..\..\..\influx\";
```

В таком случае работает как нужно